# Highlighting selected fields in dynamically added rows makes them disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, calendar

NOTE: Please no Jquery answers, need to get my head around Javascript first.

So I have added some rows to my table through insertRow(-1).
When I try to look up that table via getElementById and change the background color of a field, it works fine for the first added row:
"dates[**4**].style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';"

[image]

But not for the second added row or thereafter, they just disappear:

[image]

"dates[7].style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';

I am trying to highlight the current day (will replace the numbers 4/7 with a variable) I'm not sure whats happening, could anyone shed some light please?

*Javascript*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var hour = currentTime.getHours()
var min = currentTime.getMinutes()
//document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)

var test = currentTime.getDay();
var day = currentTime.getDate()+1;
var month = currentTime.getMonth();
var full_year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var total_days = (daysInMonth(month,full_year));
var d=1;


function daysInMonth(month,year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
var temp = test+1;
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
var table = document.getElementById("calendar");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    row.setAttribute("id", "rowClassName", 0);

for(c=1;c<8; c++){
    if(d<test){
        var newCell = row.insertCell(-1);
        newCell.innerHTML = '0';
        d++;
    } else if ((temp-test)<=total_days){
        var newCell = row.insertCell(-1);
        newCell.innerHTML = (temp-test);
        temp = temp+1;
            if(temp==day){
                var table1 = document.getElementById("rowClassName");
                var dates = table1.getElementsByTagName('td');
                dates[7].style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';

            }
        }
    }
}
```

*HTML*

```
<table id="calendar">
    <tr>
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tue</td>
        <td>Wed</td>
        <td>Thu</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Sat</td>
        <td>Sun</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
var table1 = document.getElementById("rowClassName");
```

To:

```
var table1 = document.getElementById("calendar");
```

Explanation:

You are only getting the cells for the current row using "rowClassName". Each row only consists of 7 elements (Mon-Sun). `[7]` means you are selecting the 8th cell in that row, which doesn't exist (JavaScript arrays are 0-based - the first element starts from 0).

So now what you want to do is count the number of table cells from the start of the table, inclusive of those in the first row.

Also, if you do it this way, the table cell you are trying to reference may not been created by the loop yet. You should set the red color outside of the two loops, or set a class to the cell, and use CSS to style the background color.

Snippet:

```js
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var hour = currentTime.getHours()
var min = currentTime.getMinutes()
  //document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)

var test = currentTime.getDay();
var day = currentTime.getDate() + 1;
var month = currentTime.getMonth();
var full_year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var total_days = (daysInMonth(month, full_year));
var d = 1;


function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
var temp = test + 1;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var table = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  row.setAttribute("id", "rowClassName"+1, 0);

  for (c = 1; c < 8; c++) {
    if (d < test) {
      var newCell = row.insertCell(-1);
      newCell.innerHTML = '0';
      d++;
    } else if ((temp - test) <= total_days) {
      var newCell = row.insertCell(-1);
      newCell.innerHTML = (temp - test);
      temp = temp + 1;
      if (temp == day) {
        newCell.className = "current";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.current {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="calendar">
  <tr>
    <td>Mon</td>
    <td>Tue</td>
    <td>Wed</td>
    <td>Thu</td>
    <td>Fri</td>
    <td>Sat</td>
    <td>Sun</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you try adding 14 instead of 7 to that code, the same problem arises, it still only works for the first two rows.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. This happens because the table cell you are trying to reference has not been created by the loop yet. You should set the red color outside of the two loops.